# Monitor and Log Folder Changes

Tags: server, files, directory, monitor, log

I believe this has been asked before, but I can't find any reference for what I'm trying to achieve ..

So, here is the scenario .. I'm currently in process of deploying a Samba Server for users to share files internally .. But, I'm afraid of unauthorized uploads/changes .. So, I need to track every file/folder operation under a specific directory.

So users can access `/share` upload/download files .. So, what I need to have is:

1. Save the user operation in `/var/log/users_operations.log` in which the `username/ID`, `file` changed and `timestamp` should exist
2. Sent SNMP Trap to an SNMP Server that I will deploy (This can be delayed) with the same data in the `.log` file.

Comment: Investigate `inotify` - it watches directories, and emits a message per file changed.

Comment: @waltinator .. Do you have a guide/example for usage for the `inotify` to put me on the correct path?

Comment: There are 14 `man` pages dealing with `inotify`. `man -k inotify` will find them. They contain examples, hints and other information.